# Bluetooth pairing using USB dongle with embedded Host Controller

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm attempting to create an Android and iOS app that utilizes Bluetooth to detect proximity to an object and have the app perform some action. The only thing I need to do is pair so that my app can know you are near the source, not actually perform any additional communication or have the Bluetooth receiver communicate with any hardware.

I was able to flash a BLED112 USB Dongle (BLE) and get that working with the iOS SDK when plugged into a cigarette usb car adapter, but could not find an equivalent Classic Bluetooth Dongle that would allow for the same functionality. Does anyone know of a small classic Dongle that either includes a dummy host controller or allows you to pair without a host controller which would allow for the functionality I'm trying to achieve? I need to support Classic Bluetooth for many Android phones to work since BLE isn't well supported across Android.

Thank you in advance